# Error: Module 'notebook' not installed in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm new to VS Code and I get this error when I try to code in Python there.

`Jupyter kernel cannot be started from 'Python 3.8.1 32-bit'. Using closest match Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda) instead. Error starting original kernel: Error: Module 'notebook' not installed.`

Everything works fine and I can run code. But I can't trigger parameter hints or use the intellisense feature when running code in a python script format. When I use the jupyter notebook cells format, the intellisense feature works but the paramter hints still dont work.

I've tried everything in all the other threads similar to this.

Comment: Hey @Imani Mufti. I'm a developer (specifically on the data science / notebook bits) on this extension. There looks to me like two different issues here. The Jupyter message that you list means that VS Code is trying to start up Jupyter for the Notebook editor but is failing in the Python interpreter that you have selected. The first thing to check here is if in the selected interpreter you can actually run "python -m jupyter notebook --version" that's what we use to check to see if Jupyter is supported.

Comment: The general intellisense issue (both in the notebooks and in .py files) sounds more like a language server issue. In vs code python settings do you know if you have the microsoft language server or jedi selected?

Comment: @IanHuff Thank you for the response!
Notebook issue: 
I get a message that the active interpreter does not support jupyter notebook. 

Intellisense issue: 
According the json file, jedi is disabled. The checkbox is also unchecked. 

What should I do?

Comment: I would actually file an issue on the extension github page here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues
I don't work with the language server myself, so that location would be the best spot to get help from the entire python extension team.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? That issue is closed, but the error still persists...